# evaluate bash builtins in sed in git clean filter

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to write a git clean filter and I want it to include the current date (as well as other info). It targets a tag that looks like this `$Id$`. This is what I have so far:

```
[filter "update_id"]
        clean = sed 's/\\$Id[^\\$]*/\\$Id Date: $(date)/'
```

With a file that contains $Id$, the clean filter produces this:

```
$Id Date: $(date)$
```

It's close, but how can I get the `date` evaluated, instead of printing the actual word "date"?

## Update to hone quesion

In my README file, I have this text

```
$Id$
```

I want to turn this into:

```
$24 Mar 2020 13:22:40$
```

I try to use this a my filter

```
clean = sed 's/Id/\\$(date)/'
```

I get

```
$$(date)$
```

Comment: Try to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Bodo when I do that so my filter looks like this `clean = sed "s/\\$Id[^\\$]*/\\$Id Date: $(date)/"`, the do a git add, i get error "sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
error: external filter 'sed s/\$Id[^\$]*/\$Id Date: $(date)/' failed 1
error: external filter 'sed s/\$Id[^\$]*/\$Id Date: $(date)/' failed"

Comment: When you do `date` at the command line, does the output contain slashes?

Comment: What builtin are you thinking about? `date` is an external command, not a builtin. Is that what you were referring to? Also, this will be down to how many levels of escaping you need. Can you show us the text you are parsing? Are you trying to match a literal `\$`? Or is that a `$`?

Comment: I am trying to convert ASCII text $Id$ and I have updated the question.

Comment: You can try to use a different separator for the `sed` command, e.g. use `#` instead of `/`.